# Avoid multiple subprocess Popen

Tags: python, openssl, subprocess

I am using the Popen for use case like this (this is just a skeleton/idea):

```
cipherstr = sys.argv[1]
cmd = 'openssl ciphers -v %s' % cipherstr
p = subprocess.Popen(shlex.split(cmd))
p.wait()
```

At the end of this, I consume the output as a list of ciphersuites. As you can see, every call to this module would invoke the new `openssl` process. The latency of each invocation is about 40ms (expensive for 1000s of calls).

My goal is to keep the `openssl` process active and communicate the `cipherstr` through a unix socket/pipe. This way I have one invocation of `openssl`, with the running process constantly returning the output based on varying input.

AFAICT, `openssl ciphers` does not read from a file which undermines my hypothesis.

Do you have an alternative?

Comment: Do you want async start of the process and do not wait for the output?

Comment: Have you read up on the python-openssl package? You might find something useful there, rather than using command line instructions. https://docs.python.org/2/library/ssl.html

Comment: @RolfofSaxony I have seen the python-ssl and pyOpenSSL doc. Nothing there that helps me.

Comment: @TheGodfather I do want to wait for the output. Think of the `openssl` process running as a server, each client presents a `cipherstr` and waits to hear the output.

Comment: I think I do not understand the question. Why do you talk about _1000s of calls_? My version of openssl knows 80 ciphers. So how can there be more than 80 different, valid calls? Why not do one call (without cipher name) and get all ciphers? Or do you just want to do any exercise on how to communicate with a (any) subprocess via pipes?

Comment: @hagello If you change the cipherstr, the list of ciphersuites it returns changes. What you are suggesting is writing the `openssl ciphers` functionality by myself. That is not my intention. Also, check out my comment to @TheGodfather

Comment: @SandeepY I was not aware of that. Well, I guess, you are out of luck. The only input data that `openssl ciphers` accepts is the command line argument. The command line argument is passed to the main function. So you would have to call the main function of openssl more than once, with different arguments. Without restarting the program. This is… challenging.

Comment: *"writing the openssl ciphers functionality by myself. That is not my intention"* -- unless `openssl ciphers` accepts multiple inputs; you have to implement the functionality yourself e.g., using `pyOpenSSL` (*"Nothing there that helps me."* -- I doubt that it is impossible to emulate `openssl ciphers` -- if you don't know *how* then see [ask]). Anyway, it is unrelated to `subprocess` module.

Comment: related: [How to list all openssl ciphers available in statically linked python releases?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28332448/4279)

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian This link helps since now I can invoke the C functionality through Python. The idea is to avoid Popen call and the consequent context switch costs. The C module invocation should solve that. Might as well make that as an answer?

Comment: It is a related but a different question. If you don't need to use the same version as `ssl` module then, as I said,  try pyOpenSSL  (it is pure Python now that it uses cffi to call OpenSSL C API).

Answer (score 2):

I do not think there is a way to turn a program that accepts only one word as input data into some kind of permanently running "service", responding to any number of queries.

If you do not want to re-implement `openssl ciphers -v <word>`, there seems to remain only one way to speed your queries: put the results in a cache.